# Suppress XML DTD error in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, joomla1.5, dtd, xml-validation

The XML DTD for a Joomla component is not correct, it does not contain the method="install/upgrade" attribute.  In eclipse it is annoying me because there is a permanent error showing for my project.

Is there a way to suppress this particular XML DTD error, while allowing other xml error checking to take place in the file?

Answer (score 5):

Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Validation -> "Indicate when no grammar is specified" = "Ignore"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you have module "Wild Web Developer" installed you can still get this error while using the nice answer by @eldn. You can prevent this by changing this setting for XML "Wild Web Developer":

1. Preferences
2. XML (Wild Web Developer)
3. Validation & Resolution
4. Change value for "Severity when document has no associated grammar" to "Ignore".

Now this module will also no longer bother you with the error.